# Material de estudo javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Boa tarde!

Pessoal, sou iniciante em javascript e estou procurando material ou algum site de referência principalmente sobre DOM.

Grato

Comment: Sugiro dares uma olhada na tag de javascript: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Comment: Não acho que essa pergunta seja fora do escopo. Este é um site sobre programação, então é sim do escopo do site ajudar quem quer iniciar.

Comment: @TiagoP.C perguntas específicas estão dentro do escopo, perguntas amplas e a pedir referências como esta são problemáticas. Dá uma olhada aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/819/129

Comment: Rafael, seria até o caso de pesquisar aqui mesmo, e quando for esbarrando em problemas específicos, fazer perguntas objetivas sobre cada um deles. Segue um ponto de partida sobre DOM: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdom%5D+is%3Aquestion

Comment: https://github.com/sorrycc/awesome-javascript

Comment: Rafael, veja a pergunta linkada lá no topo, no box amarelo. Pode ser um bom ponto de partida.

Comment: Obrigado pessoal